Missing parentheses in call to 'print' when read excel file
when run my script shows this error:

Error reading replacement lists from Excel: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)? (__init__.py, line 1187)
Failed to read replacement lists from Excel.

But before this script run normally, suddenly show this error. What kind of reason caused this error? The error shows error comes from __init__.py, line 1187. Where can I find this __init__.py, line 1187 in my project?
error when run this code:
def read_replacement_lists_from_excel(file_path):
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name="Sheet2", dtype=str)  # 强制转换为字符串
        replacement_keys = df["A"].tolist()
        replacement_values = df["B"].tolist()
        print(f"Replacement keys: {replacement_keys}")
        print(f"Replacement values: {replacement_values}")
        return replacement_keys, replacement_values
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading replacement lists from Excel: {e}")
        return None, None

Try to search the __init__.py in my project directory, find one but only a few rows, without 1187 rows.

Do some research on __init__.py and you will understand what it is and where they are used.

@moken True, though to "Be nice", how about giving new OP a few pointers?

Recommend starting there: What is init.py for?

Does this answer your question? Why is Python's Pandas' read_excel giving print error?

Research on SO points to Python 2/3 conflicts. Your Excel-reading module may be very old. Consider checking your module versions, posting them here, and updating your environnemnent.
